# How do I apply an image filter row by row

Tags: image, filtering, row

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm probably not using the right keywords to seek for help on this topic.

I would like to filter an image row by row, and I'm trying to work this out using `ImageData` but I can't figure how I can call a `MeanFilter` for each row and put the result back into an image.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Use the second argument of `MeanFilter`: `MeanFilter[image, {0, r}]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, however I want my radius to be a function of the row indice (I have a polar image for which I want to blur more when being far from the center)

Comment: you can also do this with `ImageFilter` making your  filter function operate only on the center row. Not sure how that will compare performamce-wise..

Comment: actually the `ImageFilter` form is  just this: `ImageFilter[Mean@First@# &, image, {0, r}]`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Kuba I came up with this:

```
polar = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
parts = ImagePartition[polar, {ImageDimensions[polar][[1]], 1}];
f[p_, {x_, y_}] := MedianFilter[p, {1, 5 + IntegerPart[x/5]}]
medPolar = ImageAssemble[MapIndexed[f, parts, {2}]]
```

[image]